# How to write a file from Apache CGI in a user home directory on CentOS

Tags: centos, permissions, selinux, cgi

I made a CGI in Python and it works unless I try to write to a file in a user's home.
I activated `allow_httpd_anon_write` and `allow_http_sys_script_anon_write` to true with graphical tool for administrating SELinux.
Then I made `home`, `home/user` and `/home/user/log_file.txt` `public_content_rw_t`.
As far as I know that is sufficient, what else I have to do? Is it simpler to write to another position?

Comment: You dealt with SELinux, but what about traditional unix permissions?